# Unable to load dependency in Play framework project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to use a library called REST Assured with the Play Framework. The documentation - https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted - gives the following artifact for Maven -

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So I altered my Build.scala file as follows to include this dependency -

```
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    "com.jayway.restassured" % "rest-assured" % "1.8.0" % "test"
  )
```

Then I try and use this library in a Java by statically importing some packages, which is what the documentation instructs me to do -

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static com.jayway.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

But this results in an Compilation error when I try and run the Play application -

> error: package com.jayway.restassured does not exist

I know that Play/sbt is retrieving the dependency because I can see a "com.jayway.restassured" directory in the play-2.1.0/repository/cache directory. However it is not showing in the play-2.1.0/repository/local directory, I don't know if that has any significance.

So what's going wrong, why can't I access this library in my Play application?

Comment: Hmmm, the imports seem to work if I place them in Java file in my /test directory. But not if I place them in a Java file in my /app directory. I get the package does not exist error if I try and use them in my files in my /app directory. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to access REST Assured from non-test code, the dependency should be defined as:

```
"com.jayway.restassured" % "rest-assured" % "1.8.0"
```

In other words, drop the `"test"` declaration. When that's present you're specifying that the library is a *test-scope* dependency. At the moment you're saying that REST Assured is not a dependency of your production code, and only needs to be scoped to code in your test tree (i.e added to the test classpath).

I guess the follow-up question is why you wish to reference a testing library from your `app` code?

Comment: I was trying out various things to get IntelliJ to work with this dependency without throwing errors. Your suggestion works. And also, if I leave "test" in the declaration" and reference the testing library from the test code this will work fine from the Play console. That is, "run", "test", and "compile" commands work without issue. However I am getting errors in IntelliJ in the import statements for this testing library saying that 'package cannot be resolved" and I cant run my app or tests from IntelliJ.

Comment: It looks like IDE support for Play is terrible considering that IntelliJ is supposed to have the best support, yet simply adding a dependency in a test package completely breaks it.

Comment: @sonicboom - Have you tried adding `rest-assured-1.8.0.jar` to your project classpath in IntelliJ? I've not used IntelliJ before but presumably that will 'make the red go away'.

Comment: I want the dependencies managed so that is not an option. And it turns out that ANY dependency I add anywhere in the app is causing the 'package cannot be resolved' errors...sigh